# Publish geometry_msgs Pose from command-line

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish to a topic the `Pose` of a robot to calculate its inverse kinematics. I am using the command:

```
ros2 topic pub --once /topic geometry_msgs/msg/Pose "{position:{1,1,1},orientation:{1,1,1,1}}"
```

but this isn't working and gives the following error

```
"Failed to populate field: getattr(): attribute name must be string".
```

What is the correct way to publish a Pose msg to topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407239/publish-geometry_msgs-pose-from-command-line/) by [ankx22](https://answers.ros.org/users/119582/ankx22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no spaces in your data which makes it an invalid YAML. I am [quoting from the ROS 2 (Foxy) documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Topics/Understanding-ROS2-Topics.html#ros2-topic-pub):

> It’s important to note that this
> argument needs to be input in YAML
> syntax.

## ROS 2

We can use the following command in ROS 2:

```
ravi@dell:~$ ros2 topic pub --once /topic geometry_msgs/msg/Pose "{position: {x: 0.2, y: 0.1, z: 0.3}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}"
publisher: beginning loop
publishing #1: geometry_msgs.msg.Pose(position=geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.2, y=0.1, z=0.3), orientation=geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion(x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, w=1.0))
```

## ROS 1

Although the question uses ROS 2 commands, it is tagged with ROS 1, i.e., noetic. Therefore, below is the equivalent ROS 1 command:

```
ravi@dell:~$ rostopic pub --once /topic geometry_msgs/Pose "{position: {x: 0.2, y: 0.1, z: 0.3}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}"
publishing and latching message for 3.0 seconds
```

Feel free to check the [ROS 1 documentation.](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_pub)

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2